# Assembly reference issue while unit testing as part of CI using TFS

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, continuous-integration

We have setup a unit test project for testing a c# class library. the c# class library has a reference to enterprise libary. The unit test executes fine while building using Visual studio. But when it is executed using TFS as part of CI, it fails due to missing assembly refernce to enterprise library.  But when we register the enterprise libary in build server GAC, it works fine.

How do we make sure that during CI unit testing, the assembly referred is not GAC but is the local copy. Trying to avoid registering all referred assemblies to gac

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't make that exclusion only for the CI unit testing - you should be doing it for both local and CI.  This will avoid the issue of a (new) dev pulling from source, and being unable to build.  Obviously licensing needs to be considered when using enterprise libraries.

Generally, if it's an external DLL that isn't hosted on NuGet, i do a "extLib" or equivalent folder in the solution, put all of my DLLs in there, and use the DLLs within that folder as a reference in the project.  Make sure the DLLs within that folder are set as "copy to output directory".